# Github cli (gh) filter repos by codeowner

Tags: github, github-cli

We have a number of repositories within an organization but I would like to be able to filter by codeowner which is defined in `.github/CODEOWNERS` file like

```
@organization_name/team_name
```

The gh cli command I am currently using is:

```
gh repo list organization_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there doesn't appear to be a built in way to do this but I think I have found a solution by chaining together a couple of commands.

You will need to install this grep extension to the GH CLI: https://github.com/k1LoW/gh-grep
`gh extensions install https://github.com/k1LoW/gh-grep`

Then you can run this shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ORG=$1
CODE_OWNER=$2

for repo_name in $(gh repo list $ORG --json name -L 1000 -q '.[].name?');
do
    gh grep $CODE_OWNER --owner $ORG --repo $repo_name --include=.github/CODEOWNERS | cut -d : -f 1
done
```

If it is saved as `get_repos_with_codeowners.sh`, then do

```bash
chmod +x get_repos_with_codeowners.sh
./get_repos_with_codeowners.sh organization_name team_name
```

It is kind of slow to grep each repo one by one, but it is ripe for multithreading (just be careful not to get blocked, there are sure to be some API limits)

Also, note the -L 1000 switch to `gh repo list`. This sets the limit for the number of repos to return (the default is 30). There is probably a way you can work out what this limit needs to be for your organisation at runtime, but I was feeling lazy so I just set this to a number which I knew to be large enough.